# docker-compose always automatically starts on computer startup

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a secondary laptop that I seem to be having some weird docker-compose startup behavior on. I recently reinstalled the laptop, and cloned a bunch of docker-compose-enabled applications that I maintain. Even though all of the services have a "restart" value of "unless-stopped", all six docker-compose applications (with several containers each) always startup when the Docker service comes up. This only happens on this one system.

I need to manually stop all of the docker-compose services whenever I start that laptop. Even though no Docker containers will be running, I'll do a "systemctl restart docker.service", and then all/some containers will start again. I'm not sure why this part is inconsistent and I don't understand enough of how the config works.

I'm not sure how to debug this. Where and how are the docker-compose configs involved in the *systemd* startup?

That system is running Ubuntu 23.04 . The other ones (the ones that are behaving correctly) are running Manjaro. I'm using docker-compose config version 3.9 .

Comment: Why didn't you use docker compose up -d or docker compose down instead of managing using the service? you can down them and just up -d when it is needed.

Comment: That's the problem. They're all stopped when I restart that system, and all back again when it comes back up. It only happens on this one system.